# Read Table Row and add effect to row on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Am adding dynamic data to Table , from AJAX call , I want to read the row which contain "BLOCK" string in it , if it is there add RED color to it ?

How can I achieve this.......?
Below is my current code

```
                  success: function(xml) {
                  var block_count;
                  var xmlDOM = $(xml);
                  block_count = $(xml).find('item').length;
                  xmlDOM.find("item").slice(position,position+page_size).each(function()       {
                            var $this=$(this);
                            var $user=$this.find("user").text();
                            var $tag=$this.find("tag").text();
                            var $action=$this.find("action").text();
                            var $time=$this.find("time").text();
            $("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow'><td>"+$time+"</td> <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");
                    });


         <table id='datatable' width="100%" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" style="line-height: .9em;">
                    <thead>
                            <tr id='tableheader'>
                                    <th>Time</th><th>User</th><th>tag</th><th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
         </table>
```

EDIT 1:How can I add red color if that row contain BLOCK string in that ....?

EDIT 2: I tried as below code

```
$color = /BLOCK/.test($action) ? 'red' : '';
$("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow "+$color+"'><td>"+$time+"</td>   <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");

.datarow.red {
background-color: red;
}
```

The table looks like this image[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think with use of `:contains`

```
$("#datatable tr:contains('BLOCK')").addClass('red');
```

or this way:

```
$("#datatable").find("tr:contains(BLOCK)").addClass('red');
```

Comment: Does your any tr contains this text `BLOCK`? it'll work only when you get the text in the tr.